# a.s. convergence and Glivenko-Cantelli theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, statistics, convergence-divergence

Assume that we have a sample $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n$ is a sample from, for example, Poisson distribution with probability mass function $p_{i}$ and cdf $\mathbb{F}$. Then, for $i\in\mathbb{N}$ let
$$
\bar{p}_{n,i} = \frac{\sum_{j=1}^{n} 1 \{ X_j = i \}}{n}
$$
is empirical estimator.

The Glivenko-Cantelli theorem says:
$$
\|\bar{\mathbb{F}}_n - F\|_\infty \overset{\text{a.s.}}{\to} 0
$$
where $\bar{\mathbb{F}}_n$ is empirical cdf.

The queston: assume that $\tilde{p}_n$ is another strongly consistent estimator of $p$, i.e. $\tilde{p}_{n}$ converges a.s. to $p$ in $l_{2}$ norm. Note, in $l_{2}$, not point-wise.

Is then
$$
\|\tilde{\mathbb{F}}_n - F\|_\infty \overset{\text{a.s.}}{\to} 0
$$
where $\tilde{\mathbb{F}}_n$ is cdf for the estimator $\tilde{p}_n$?

Comment: What is the context of this question? Why do you want to know? It would also depend on the definition of "strongly consistent," for example, the definition may simply be the same property you are trying to prove.

Comment: I am reading course in Asymptotic Statistics. We studied Glivenko Cantelli theorem and this question came to my mind. Strong consistency: is when the estimator converges a.s. to the true distribution. The question: is convergence a.s. to the true equivalent to result of Glivenco-Cantelli?

Comment: If by "the estimator converges a.s. to the true distribution" you mean that $||\tilde{F}_n-F||_{\infty} \rightarrow 0$ almost surely, then the property you are trying to prove is already the property you are starting with.

Comment: no, I mean $\tilde{p}_{n} \overset{\text{a.s.}}{\to} p$, where $\tilde{p}_{n}$ is the estimator and $p$ is true probability mass function

Comment: Note that $\tilde{p}_n$ is an infinite dimensional vector. So then you really mean that $||\tilde{p}_n-p||_{\infty}\rightarrow 0$ almost surely?

Comment: in all $l_{k}$ spaces. I think this is a standard definition of strong consistency...

Comment: I am fairly certain that, once definitions are specified, this will be a simple problem with a 1 or 2 line solution.  That is why it seems very much like a test question. I can think of 2 particular definitions of "strong consistency" for infinite dimensional problems under which your problem is both meaningful and easy to solve. I encourage you to work on the problem by starting with the definitions and thinking about the fundamental difference between the information you are given and the property you are trying to prove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

It really depends on how you define $\tilde{{p}_{n,i}}$, for example if you let $$\tilde{{p}_{n,i}} =\overline{{p}_{n,i}}+\frac{1}{n}$$
Then clearly, $ ( \tilde{{p}_{n,i}} ,n) $ is clearly a strongly consistent estimator of $p_i$, however 
$$\tilde{\mathbb{F}}_n( \infty)-F(\infty)= \infty$$
for all $n$, which means $\| \tilde{\mathbb{F}}_n-F\|_{\infty}$ can't converge to $0$.

---

So we'll be more specific on your "strong consistency" by giving to two following conditions:

- $\tilde{p_{n,i}}$ is a strongly consistent estimator of $p_i$
- $\tilde{\mathbb{F}}_n(\infty)= \sum_{i \in \mathbb{N}}\tilde{p_{n,i}}$ converges to $1$ almost surely

So following the same argument in Glivenko-Cantelli theorem's proof, we see that for all $m$, we have:
$$\| \tilde{\mathbb{F}}_n-F\|_{\infty} \le \max_{0 \le i \le m} |\tilde{\mathbb{F}}_n(m)-F(m)|+|F(\infty)-F(m)|+|\tilde{\mathbb{F}}_n(\infty)-\tilde{\mathbb{F}}_n(m)| $$
Thus by the assumed strong consistency, we imply that
$$\limsup_n \| \tilde{\mathbb{F}}_n-F\|_{\infty}  \le 2|1-F(m)|$$
for all $m$, or
$$\limsup_n \| \tilde{\mathbb{F}}_n-F\|_{\infty} =0$$
$\square$

Comment: hm, I think there is a miss understanding here. The strong consistency is: $\tilde{p}_{n}$ converges to $p$ a.s. in $l_{2}$ norm. Then, is this equivalent to Glivenco-Cantelli result?

Comment: Hm, if it is a misunderstanding, you should clarify it in your initial statement, because the problem with definitions has been shown long ago in the comment section. And, do you really want the convergence in $l_2$  norm?

Comment: Anyways, if your $\tilde{p}_n$ satisfies the desired convergence, $\tilde{F}_{n}(\infty)$ must converge a.s to $1$ and each $\tilde{p}_{n,i}$ must be a strongly consistent esimator of $p_i$. So what I proved is the equivalency between the desired convergence and my two conditions.

Comment: $\tilde{\mathbb{F}}_n(\infty)= \sum_{i \in \mathbb{N}}\tilde{p_{n,i}}$ converges to $1$ almost surely. What do you mean? $\tilde{\mathbb{F}}_n(\infty) = 1$ for all $n$, isn't it?

Comment: It depends on how you define $\tilde{p}_{n,i}$, right? $\sum_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \tilde{p}_{n,i}$ is not necessarily equal to $1$.

Comment: hm... the estimator of probability mass function must equal to $1$. Don't you agree?

Comment: Yeah, it's reasonable. However, you will have be another constraint for the choice of of $(\tilde{p}_{n,i} , i )$, that is $$\sum_i \tilde{p}_{n,i}=1$$. And in my solution, I even relaxed that constraint, so that we don't need to have equality but just an a.s convergence.